# Power to light then out to outlet and switch wiring question

Tags: electrical

[image]I have power coming into this can light and then to the switch, and then to another can in the room. I would like to have an outlet that comes on with the switch. I assume I would just pigtail with the wires that are running to the second light with my outlet wires? Just want to make sure this is correct.

Comment: Where will this new outlet be located, in the ceiling?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could use the hot, neutral and ground from the 2nd light or the first to power your switched receptacle and pull the wire to wherever you want the receptacle.